# Creating an object of an interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am learning to use entity framework( still I am novice in entity framework and C#) ,

while going through one of the tutorials , I came across the following piece of code:

```
 public class EntityF : IEntityWithChangeTracker,IEntityWithKey
    {
        private IEntityChangeTracker changetracker;

        public void SetChangeTracker(IEntityChangeTracker changetracker)
        {
            this.changetracker = changetracker;
        } 
    }
```

Can we make use of referencing one more interface within a class like this?:

```
 private IEntityChangeTracker changetracker;
```

And not even implemented the methods defined in the **IEntityChangeTracker** interface.

What could be the purpose of using instance of an interface **IEntityChangeTracker** in the example here.

Until now (while practising C# tutorials), I was defining some skeleton methods in the interface and the class which inherits it needs to provide the implementation for them . This is a classic example, but the code here is something different . Can anybody please let me know the purpose of defining interfaces like this?

Comment: can you show the declaration of IEntityChangeTracker and IEntityWithKey.

Comment: Its a system defined interface using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What could be the purpose of using instance of an interface IEntityChangeTracker in the example here.

When accepting an interface instead of a concrete implementation, you're creating de-coupling between both classes. That means, the caller of the code is free to pass any object which **implements** the above interface, instead of a specific concrete type. You're saying to the caller *"you may pass any object implementing the above interface, i only care about the members/methods declared by it*"

This way you're also opening a door to [*Dependency Injection*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and allowing the client to support [*Interface Segregation Principle*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)